# @id not displaying when creating a listview

Tags: android-studio

When dragging and dropping in design to create a list view, the only code that got created in my xml was :

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

No `android:id="@id/example"/` was created. I need to call it for my Fragment class

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);

    String[] menuItems={"Example1","Example2","Example3"};

    ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.example);


    return view;
}
```

I can't call my ListView because android studio wont let me create an id for it. I get the following error when writing the code in **Cannot resolve symbol '@id/example', Validates resources references inside Android XML files**

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a new id, you need to add a `+` to it:

```
android:id="@+id/text"
```

See the Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout#write

Answer (score 1):

## ID

> Any View object may have an integer ID associated with it, to uniquely
>   identify the View within the tree. When the app is compiled, this ID
>   is referenced as an integer, but the ID is typically assigned in the
>   layout XML file as a string, in the id attribute. This is an XML
>   attribute common to all View objects (defined by the View class) and
>   you will use it very often. The syntax for an ID, inside an XML tag
>   is:

```
android:id="@+id/example"
```

> The at-symbol (@) at the beginning of the string indicates that the
>   XML parser should parse and expand the rest of the ID string and
>   identify it as an ID resource. The plus-symbol (+) means that this is
>   a new resource name that must be created and added to our resources
>   (in the R.java file). There are a number of other ID resources that
>   are offered by the Android framework. When referencing an Android
>   resource ID, you do not need the plus-symbol, but must add the android
>   package namespace, like so:

```
android:id="@android:id/example"
```

> With the android package namespace in place, we're now referencing an
>   ID from the android.R resources class, rather than the local resources
>   class.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. I chose Frozenkoi first because he answered first, but thanks.

Comment: @LuiH any time sir no problem i am happy because this its helps you